# Postgresql how to get a specified text from text data

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

I created a table has a column store text data. I want to get specified text value from the column. I want to get `PAYMENTDATE` value. How can I do?

```
"{"SALEDATE":"2017-11-01 12:46:29","PAYMENTDATE":"2017-11-01 12:50:49"}"
```

Comment: why dont use a JSON column instead? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-json.html

Comment: You are right. I know JSON type. But I have to use text data.

Comment: You still can cast the text field as JSON and work with it. `text_data::JSON`

Comment: I solved such as thanks. columnName::json->>'PAYMENTDATE' as paymentDate

Answer (score 1):

If you trim the leading and trailing `"` from the string, you'll have a json-formatted string. You could then just cast it to `json` and use the `->>` operator to extract data from it:

```
SELECT TRIM(BOTH '"' FROM mycol)::JSON->>'PAYMENTDATE'
FROM   mytable
```

Comment: My guess those `"` are the result from printing the field content.

Comment: columnName::json->>'PAYMENTDATE' as paymentDate. This is worked thanks.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza so it's even easier then - just lose the `trim` call